# Trigger created with compilation errors. PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I've been searching for a while how to resolve this issue and couldn't find anything helpful.
Why this trigger is created with compilation errors?
The warning im getting

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER peope_in_dept
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE on emp
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     VARIABLE v NUMBER;
     EXECUTE :v := count_people_in_dept(:new.deptno)
     IF :v <= 0 or :v >= 10 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000,'Nieodpowiednia liczba pracownikow');
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: What compilation error? You haven't given us any details.

Comment: Right, @Dai. On the other hand, for someone - who actually uses Oracle - it is more than obvious what's wrong. Other people probably won't / can't answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors. Should be

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER peope_in_dept
  2     AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
  3     ON emp
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  DECLARE
  6     v  NUMBER;
  7  BEGIN
  8     v := count_people_in_dept (:new.deptno);
  9
 10     IF    v <= 0
 11        OR v >= 10
 12     THEN
 13        raise_application_error (-20000, 'Nieodpowiednia liczba pracownikow');
 14     END IF;
 15  END;
 16  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

---

However, I suspect it won't work if `count_people_in_dept` function counts employees in `emp` table. Why? Because table is *mutating*:

```
SQL> UPDATE emp SET comm = 1 WHERE deptno = 10;
UPDATE emp SET comm = 1 WHERE deptno = 10
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.COUNT_PEOPLE_IN_DEPT", line 6
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PEOPE_IN_DEPT", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.PEOPE_IN_DEPT'


SQL>
```

Now, it depends on what you really are doing in that function. One way out is to set the function to be an autonomous transaction; another one is to use compound trigger; the third option is to use custom type and a package. Or, modify the process altogether (i.e. avoid the trigger).

Comment: Thanks for giving such a long answer! I've wanted to create a trigger that gives an error after analyzing how many employees are in a certain department, I've tried using INSTEAD OF trigger but didnt work for me so I created a function counting the numbers of employees.

Comment: You're welcome. OK, use the function, but not in a trigger - perform that check while inserting (or updating/deleting) rows into the table. I presume that's some kind of a PL/SQL program unit, so - use IF-THEN-ELSE.

Comment: It's exactly PL/SQL, but I would like to make it possible to insert anyone, not caring how many employees there are and after inserting I want to make a trigger give an error. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: That just doesn't make sense. Suppose it is Oracle Forms application - you let users enter 15 employees, they spend 10 minutes to fill all the data, hit the "Submit" button and then you inform them that there's an error. What are they supposed to do now? Go back and delete some rows? Call you on the phone? Why wouldn't you rather perform that check while users work on it and save them (and you) some time & pain?

Comment: I guess, u could call that an exercise for the sake of doing an exercise. But youre absolutely right, it doesnt make sense

Comment: @Littlefoot - *"they spend 10 minutes to fill all the data, hit the "Submit" button and then you inform them that there's an error"*. This would make sense if you think about the case of moving employees from one  department to another; you'd need to wait until you'd shuffled all the employees before validating that you'd met the business rules about department size.

Answer (score 1):

> Why this trigger is created with compilation errors?

Because you are trying to create a SQL/Plus global bind variable inside a PL/SQL procedure and then using `EXECUTE` rather than just calling the function (and you missed a `;` statement terminator).

The correct syntax would be:

```sql
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v := count_people_in_dept(:new.deptno);
  IF v <= 0 or v >= 10 THEN
```

Then it would compile. However, it still won't work as the table would be mutating as the trigger is running.

---

Instead, you can use a statement trigger rather than a row trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER people_in_dept
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE on emp
DECLARE
  v_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO   v_count
  FROM   dept d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN emp e
         ON (e.deptno = d.deptno)
  GROUP BY d.deptno
  HAVING COUNT(e.deptno) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 9
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
  
  raise_application_error(-20000,'Nieodpowiednia liczba pracownikow');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    -- Do nothing.
    NULL;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=289cc17d435de643b465c4ec7946d19a)*

You could also write it as a compound trigger that aggregates the changes in `deptno` and then only checks the changed values using your function; however, that is a lot more complicated.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the rule that departments can't have minus employees. I wonder how that might occur. Although I suppose have worked with a few negative people over the years....

Comment: Also, I think the original rule specified that a department can't have zero employees. In which case we need to use DEPT with a left join on EMP to find all the extant departments

Comment: @APC I'd spotted that too after your first comment and was just updating it.